# Typescript Interface causing <Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite> in generic

Tags: typescript

```
    type Recursion<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends string
        ? T[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
            ? Recursion<T[K], keyof T[K]>
            : K
        : never

    const a = <Data extends Record<string,unknown> >(data:Data extends never ? Data : Recursion<Data, keyof Data>)=>{

    const b = (data: any) => {}
    b(data)
    
    }
```

this is fine, no error or what so ever

then I changed the constraint of `Data` to an interface

```
    interface DocumentData {
          [field: string]: any;
    }

    const c = <Data extends DocumentData>(data:Data extends never ? Data : Recursion<Data, keyof Data>)=>{

    const d = (data: any) => {}
    d(data) // <---Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite!!!

    }
```

and I got this error

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JAFwngDgpgBASlAxgVwE4GcCWB7AdgHgBUAaGAaRigA8QpcATdGAayjGwDMZCA%20GAXnKUadRjHQhUmXAHMAUMGAB%20bgG0yAXWG0GTBImyp6%20CVNmlkuZrmwB3XDwWKV%20tFjxF1G0q3ZdCXo6KwABc5E5huFAAblCocnIwSTAGuBIwAIYCMPgAIhkgWdQ6YvqGxqbSMsSW1nYOMDwAFPQFGSH5hdqiTFGxqDAqnVlhrhg4BMM%20bJwwwzwAlPw8AN4JwKnpAEbZLW1hGbhgCwJ8KwC%20iclbe4ULV0kPMJcJyTDStKgcGYiwudgoAC2dBAwxgazekJgqg4mCgABt6GFKrINAcjgBuJ4vN6bEApbJ5NrdXRzAHIYG4UFtZqtQodYnFHowPpxQZzYmjJBuCZEwrTPwcwqLZZrBR4mD0XZ09qZI4nZbgy7Aei3DInAD0GpyAFo9YRILBpBJDiBMAUJu8mNRfugsLF4WBJVAoBA5VKINg7Zgto73rhYbhMLQAIRh17JS5AA)

What goes wrong?

Comment: Unnecessary conditional type in the parameters: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYHsB2AeAKgDRQDSUEAHsBNgCapQDWEImAZlPgHxQC8p5KjXpRUwZOmwBzAFBQoAfk4BtEgF1B1OgzjxMyWrjETpxRNkbZMAd2xc58xbAQoMOAqrXFmrDvk-2jlAAXKQOodgQAG4QyADcMjJ62GJQAIZ8ULgAImnAGZRaIrr6hsaSUmYWVrZcXAAUtHlpobn5msIMkTHITm0ZobquWHj93izsUP1cAJR8PADeDsmpAEaZjc2hadggc7yLAL4J8qub+TMJx4mS1MhsafDQ2ZhIALY0wP1QS-LKbOgIAAbWihcrSNTbXZXRIrYBQeCZHIdbRTV6ID7YL7NYjfQqdZxINAjHLjXxTOrnFpTZr7RbLHCpWgbJr5KF7eY-a7yWhUy5QAD0AqyAFoxfhwNBJGIdsB0HkRlB0AxKE9UBgYkCQFBaBAIGB0nQoGBMOr0KstUrsADsOhqABCR0ya5AA)

Comment: When a conditional type checks `any`, the result is a union of the true and false branches (that is, `type F<T> = T extends string ? 1 : 0` with `F<any>` produces `1 | 0`), and so your `Recursion<T, K>` is illegally circular if `any` appears anywhere as a property/subproperty type of `T`.  `never` would also be a problem.  My suggestion here would be to refactor so that you are doing a straight mapped type which automatically terminates at primitives like `any` and `never`.  ...

Comment: ... And I really don't understand the point of `K` as its own parameter, since it seems you only ever make it `keyof T`, so you might as well just iterate over `keyof T`. Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVaVxw).  If that meets your needs I can write it up, but maybe you could [edit] the question to remove the unnecessary `K` parameter?  You can reproduce your issue without it [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WoDrpw).  Let me know.